# Extracting Code of R function to be used in knitr with controlled width

Tags: r, knitr, sweave

We can use `formatR::usage(lm)` to get the arguments of `lm` function and can use the following command to redirect the output to `knitr`:

```
<<test, code=formatR::usage(lm), eval=FALSE>>=
@
```

I wonder if there is such function to get the `lm` function code to redirect to `knitr`.

### Edited

Got the code of `lm` function to be used in `knitr` using the following code (as suggested by @JoshO'Brien):

```
<<test, code=lm, eval=FALSE>>=
@
```

But could not figure out how to control the `width` of `knitr` output.

Comment: Does `body` give you what you want?

Comment: What don't you like about the output of `<<test, code=lm, eval=FALSE>>=` ?

Comment: Thanks Dason and @JoshO'Brien for your helpful comments. Would you mind to change your comments to answers and also help me to control the width of output. Thanks

Comment: @MYaseen208 I would, but I don't immediately see how to control the width.

Comment: Thanks @JoshO'Brien for your interest in my problem. I also tried different methods but could not figured out how to control the `width` of `knirt` output of `<<test, code=lm, eval=FALSE>>= @`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To embed a 'tidy' *definition* of some function see [Yihui's self-explanatory existing code](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/pretty/),

```
<<insert-fun, echo=FALSE>>=
insert_fun = function(name) {
  read_chunk(lines = capture.output(dump(name, '')), labels = paste(name, 'source', sep = '-'))
}
@

<<insert-lm, echo=FALSE>>=
insert_fun('lm')
@

<<lm-source, eval=FALSE, tidy=TRUE, tidy.opts=list(width.cutoff=30)>>=
@
```

[Example Rnw and Rmd Gist](https://gist.github.com/Thell/843053aee9fcc53a7b83)

---

When output is going to latex, there are sometimes have issues with getting line breaks to stay within the page margins. Its a known issue with multiple fixes that have various drawbacks. Like this one where you get the full function within the margins but without the pretty coloring... It is all a matter of trade-offs and/or effort you put into a solution. :)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{inconsolata}

<<echo=FALSE>>=
options(width=60)

listing <- function(x, options) {
  paste("\\begin{lstlisting}[language=R,basicstyle=\\ttfamily,breaklines=true]\n",
    x, "\\end{lstlisting}\n", sep = "")
}
knit_hooks$set(source=listing, output=listing)

insert_fun = function(name) {
  read_chunk(lines = capture.output(dump(name, '')), labels = paste(name, 'source', sep = '-'))
}

@

<<insert-lm, echo=FALSE>>=
insert_fun('lm')
@

\begin{document}

<<lm-source, eval=FALSE, tidy=TRUE, tidy.opts=list(width.cutoff=50)>>=
@

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Thell for your answer. But your approach gives the code in list. Any thoughts.

Comment: Thanks @Thell for your help. Last two chunk codes are not giving any output.

Comment: I'm not getting any output of the last two R chunk codes.

Comment: Yes, I did that but not getting any output of these R chunk codes.

Comment: What is the purpose of `<<lm-source, results="hide", tidy=TRUE, tidy.opts=list(width.cutoff=30)>>=
@`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79843/discussion-between-thell-and-myaseen208).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is this possible to breake the line for some comments which go out the width of page?